# Как послать запрос на json выборку из действия контроллера asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Всем привет! Мне нужно послать запрос на посторонний сайт по определенной ссылке и получить json результат. С помощью каких средств это можно сделать на [asp.net](http://asp.net) mvc?
Можно примеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public MyObject GetMyObject(string url) {
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
    MyObject someone = (MyObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
    return someone;
}
```

Comment: Вот это ответ:) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял: запрос можно послать и получить ответ пакетом `HTTP`, используя например, сокеты. В ответе будет пакет `HTTP`, то есть, заголовки `HTTP` и сама страница html... Обрабатываете и храните в формате `Json`.

Comment: Нет ли пути попроще? Например библиотеки упрощающей это.